# getImageURI no esta definido para google.charts.Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

Me podrian ayudar me aparece es el error que no es una función no definida cuando uso el google.charts.Bar , necesito poder convertir la grafica en una imagen para descargarla en pdf

Comment: Deberias de mostrarnos tu codigo y el mensaje de error para poder ayudarte

Comment: ya mostre mi codigo

Comment: me sale este error en la vista chart.getImageURI is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
//este es mi codigo   
//Grafia en barra
    function chartBar(arrayReport, titulo, grafica_id, tipo, id_export){
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart','bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){ drawChartBar(arrayReport, titulo, grafica_id, tipo, id_export) });
    }

    //Inicia grafica de barra
    function drawChartBar(json_data, titulo, grafica_id, tipo, id_export){

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(json_data);

            var options = {
                width:1000,
                height:300,
                chart: {
                    title: titulo,
                  },
                chartArea: {width: '60%'},
                hAxis: {
                  minValue: 0,
                  format: '0'
                },
                bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById(grafica_id));

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
                imgUrls[id_export].push(chart.getImageURI());
            });
            chart.draw(data,options);
    }
```